# Why can't I bind input type "checkbox" in cellTemplate?

Tags: angular-ui-grid

**Here is my plunker example:** http://plnkr.co/edit/Tc9FRHAEoQlOqy7sk1Ae?p=preview

**What I'm trying to do:**
Bind the checkbox html from field04 in my data to the cell using cellTemplate and still have access to its ng-click function.

Code in app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.grid', 'ngSanitize']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', function ($scope, $log, $sce) {

$scope.myViewModel = {
  someProp:'abc',
  showMe : function(){
     alert(this.someProp);
  }
};

$scope.gridOptions = {
};

$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
     { name: 'field01', field: 'field01' },
     { name: 'field02', field: 'field02'},
     { name: 'field03', field: 'field03', cellTemplate: '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.entity.field03" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();getExternalScopes().showMe()">'},
     { name: 'field04', field: 'field04', cellTemplate: 'viewTemplate2'},
     { name: 'field05', field: 'field05', cellTemplate: 'viewTemplate2'} 
   ];

$scope.gridOptions.data = [
  {
      "field01": "one",
      "field02": "01",
      "field03": false,
      "field04": '',
      "field05": '',
  },
  {
      "field01": "two",
      "field02": "02",
      "field03": false,
      "field04": '',
      "field05": '',
  },
  {
      "field01": "three",
      "field02": "03",
      "field03": false,
      "field04": '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.entity.field03" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();getExternalScopes().showMe()">',
      "field05": '<div><a href="#" title="icon link"><img class="icon" alt=""/></a></div>',
  }
];
$scope.toggle = function() {
  alert("toggled");
}
}]);
```

Code from index.html:

```
<body>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ui-grid="gridOptions" external-scopes="myViewModel" class="grid"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="viewTemplate2">
  <span ng-bind-html="row.entity[col.field]"></span>
</script>

</body>
```

I am achieving the correct effect in field03 if I write the html in the columnDef.  Thanks to TomMorgan's plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/9eRg9Yjl2ooeSuWMJ8x2?p=preview.

I can fill the cellTemplate with html from the data in field05.

Why is it not working for my checkbox in field04?

I'm new to angularjs and its difficult to separate "ui-grid" solutions from "ng-grid" solutions.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't put your desired HTML in a cellTemplate within the columnDefs? Is it because the HTML you want is coming in as your data? The way you've achieved it for field03 would be the correct way of doing it. When working with ui-grid (which is ng-grid 3.0), you want to put your custom HTML in a cellTemplate.

Comment: When the data comes in I have to filter it somehow.  For example, field03 is "permissions", if "permissions" : "canEdit" is true I need to display an edit icon.  Also, the row item may have a document linked to it, if so I need to display a document link icon right next to the "canEdit" icon in field03.

In "ui-grid" I can't figure out how to run scripts like that as the data gets loaded into the grid.  I could do it in jqgrid using
    afterInsertRow: function(rowid, data){}

Comment: You can build a custom filter in angular to handle that logic. You can then call that filter for that column as follows: `{ name: 'field04', field: 'field04', cellFilter: 'myNewFilter'}`

Comment: I tried the cellFilter route first, however it does not handle html.  Whatever gets returned from the filter is read as "text only", so my html gets printed out in the cell.  CellFilter also does not work if you use cellTemplate.

Comment: If you're using a cellTemplate, you can add the filter like this: `cellTemplate: '<span>{{COL_FIELD | myFilter}}</span>'`. Additionally, you can return HTML using a filter. Inject the $sce service into the filter and have the filter return this: `return $sce.trustAsHtml("<span>custom html stuff </span>");`

Comment: The filter is causing an infinitely accumulating "ReferenceError: $sce is not defined".  I was referencing $sce in my grid controller, am I supposed to reference it somewhere else for the filter to work?

Comment: You need to inject the $sce service into the new filter, not into your controller. Eg. `app.filter('myNewFilter', function ($sce) {...`

Comment: Injecting the $sce service into the new filter did get rid of the error, however the filter is still printing the html markup into the cell as text.  I will link a separate plunker example for this problem when I can.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. If you can produce a plunkr, I'm happy to walk you through it. The $sce service should allow you to return HTML to your view.

Answer (score 10):

I am not sure if I understand your code.

You shouldn't put html code in your data. So I changed it to:

```
   $scope.gridOptions.data = [
      {
          "field01": "one",
          "field02": "01",
          "field03": false,
          "field04": '',
          "field05": '',
      },
      {
          "field01": "two",
          "field02": "02",
          "field03": false,
          "field04": '',
          "field05": '',
      },
      {
          "field01": "three",
          "field02": "03",
          "field03": false,
          "field04": '',
          "field05": '',
      }
    ];
```

Next: In your cell template pass a reference to the value that changes:

```
 { name: 'field03', field: 'field03', cellTemplate: '<input type="checkbox"
  ng-model="row.entity.field03" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();
  getExternalScopes().showMe(row.entity.field03)">'}
```

Note that function `showMe()` now has a parameter:

```
showMe(row.entity.field03)
```

In the external scope you should react to the parameter:

```
$scope.myViewModel = {
  someProp:'abc',
  showMe : function(value){
     alert('toggled to: '+value);
  }
};
```

(You don't really need `someProp`)

The `$scope.toggle()` function can be removed, or can be called from `showMe()`.

Furthermore, I added some debugging help to your html to show you that the binding works pretty well:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ui-grid="gridOptions" external-scopes="myViewModel" class="grid"></div>
  <hr>
  {{gridOptions.data | json}}
</div>
```

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Gw3eb89IJJIezg4coljb?p=preview). Is that what you want?

**Update:**

Here is another [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LiSIaVKMDg6FqNg3JWKh?p=preview) that has the checkbox in column 4.

Comment: Putting html in the data is something I do client side. When the data comes in I check each items "permissions" properties.  For example, if "permissions" has "canEdit : true", "hasDocument : true" I need to display those corresponding icons in a single cell.  The document icon needs to have a link associated with it to the actual file. In jqgrid I solved this by using an "afterInsertRow" function.  But in ui-grid I do not know how to do the same thing.  Should I post a new question regarding this?  If I did it correctly I wouldn't have a checkbox cellTemplate problem?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hy4TJCJMO94gEGqsM2o0?p=preview) with appScope, external-scopes don't work anymore.

I've made some changes to work with new appScope:

```
 { name: 'field03', field: 'field03', cellTemplate: '<input type="checkbox"
  ng-model="row.entity.field03" ng-click="grid.appScope.showMe(row.entity.field03)">'}
```

In the scope you should react to the parameter but I've pulled from myViewModel and just created a function inside $scope:

```
$scope.showMe : function(value){
     alert('toggled to: '+value);
};
```

You can test code from version 15 against my version 16. My new version runs ok but 15 no.

Comment: Please include the relevant code bits in your answer.

Comment: I've never post here. It made some time to figure why my code wasn't go to the answer.

Comment: The plunkr's output is broken. Can't see table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $sce to tell ng-bind-html that HTML content you are binding is safe.

I have forked your plunker and the solution for your question is http://plnkr.co/edit/JyTaF8niJlf9Wpb775kb?p=preview

```
    app.filter('unsafe', function ($sce) {
       return $sce.trustAsHtml;
    });
```

You have to use this filter with ng-bind-html